# Generating public/private key pair based on input

Tags: cryptography, openssl, pki

OpenSSL provides tools to generate random public/private key pairs.  Is there any mechanism to deterministically generate a pair based on some initial value?

For example, given the string `'abcd'`, generate a public/private key pair, such that the same public/private key pair can be generated again using the same string.

Comment: @owlstead Certainly. Ideally the password would be the same length as the key, then there would be no loss of entropy. But then you wouldn't need the password, would you?

Answer (score 4):

For sure, just use your password in a PBKDF to generate a key like array of bytes (random salt and high iteration count required). Then use this array of bytes as seed for a PRNG. Make sure that you always use the same PRNG! Then use that PRNG as input for [RSA_generate_key](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html). Make sure that generate key implementation is not changed.

Please read the answers on [Initialize a PRNG with a password](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6086/initialize-a-prng-with-a-password) on crypto.stackexchange.com. Note that usually the private key is encrypted instead, e.g. using the PKCS#12 container. Note that both PKCS#12 containers and the method above are vulnerable to brute force attacks. Most passwords do deliver a very limited amount of entropy, making these brute force attacks more feasible. The advantage of the PKCS#12 container is that you do not have to store it with the ciphertext, it is only required during signature generation or decryption. Using a 128 bit hex value as password would alleviate the issue of brute forcing, but you likely won't be able to remember it.

Note that RSA key pair generation takes a lot of time (and finding a large prime has a nondeterministic running time, so it may take very long for specific key pairs). EC F(p) keys would be much less cumbersome.

Feasible? Certainly. Useful? Possibly. Fraught with danger? Certainly.

Comment: If you have to ask how to do this, then you should probably not be doing this :P

Comment: Somehow I feel that's true for just about anything that has to do with cryptography.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Yes, but this is moving from the well worn paths. And if you loose the path you will likely encounter spiders - and mean elves.

Comment: "Then use this array of bytes as seed for a PRNG" - you have to be careful here. OpenSSL will use the `RDRAND` engine if available, and that does not take seeds or produce deterministic outputs. And you have to jump through hoops to disable the behavior. See [Engines and RDRAND](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization#ENGINEs_and_RDRAND).